# For loop to show next item

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a div containing an order list and a button below. Now what I would like to happen is that when the button is clicked you add a class to the first li and when the button is clicked again it jumps to the second li and so on until it gets to the last li and then it stops. Here's my code.

At the moment I'm using console.log just see what happens but every time I click it shows all the list item.

```
<style>
  .hl { background: green; }
</style>

<div class="large-2 large-centered columns">
    <ol>
     <li>some</li> 
     <li>some</li> 
     <li>some</li> 
     <li>some</li> 
     <li>some</li> 
     <li>some</li> 
     <li>some</li> 
    </ol>
    <button>Click Me</button>
</div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var item = $('ol').find('li');
    var btn = $('button');

    btn.click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      for (var i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
         console.log([i]);
      };
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Your code is telling it to iterate through all the list items.  Can you clarify what you want to happen when the button is clicked?

Comment: You should only get a number per click in the console. If you want to get the `li`, do `console.log(item[i]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $items = $('ol').find('li');
    var $btn = $('button');

    $btn.click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $current = $items.filter('.hl').removeClass('hl'),
            $next = $current.next();
        if (!$next.length) {
            $next = $items.first();
        }
        $next.addClass('hl')
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5hCXQ/)

Answer (score 2):

Try to cycle your items like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var item = $('ol').find('li');
    var btn = $('button'),
        i = 0;

    btn.click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        item.removeClass('hl').eq(i++ % item.length).addClass('hl');
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yV9CM/

Comment: Bah, this modulo thing is dope ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var idx = 0;
    $('button').click(function () {
        if (idx < $('li').length) $('li').removeClass().eq(idx).addClass('hl');
        idx++;
    });
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/LVt9p/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use the click event to find the next `li` and move the classname, checking that there is a next li so you don't proceed after the last.

```
$(function(){
    $('button').click(function(e){
      var nextLi = $('li.active').next();
        if( nextLi.length == 1 ){ 
          $('li.active').removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vbrr2/)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a `for`, but instead increment a counter each time you click:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var item = $('ol').find('li');
    var btn = $('button');
    var i = 0;

    btn.click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log(item[i]);
      i++;
      if (i === item.length) {  //you start from the beginning if you reach end
         i = 0;
      }  
    });
});
```

please note that if you change `li` elements after page load, you'll have to recreate `item` variable, and reset the `i` counter.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are finding all of the lis within the and looping over them.

It seems like what you want is

```
var $item = $('ol').find('li').filter(':not(.myClass)').filter(':first');
$item.addClass("myClass");
```

Comment: This won’t loop through all the items. When the second one has the class, the 1st, 3rd, 4th, … will be selected by the filter #1 – and then the second one selects the first LI again out of those.

Comment: My understanding of the question was that the author wanted each item to get the class, but only one per click. Not that it should be removed from earlier ones with each click.

Comment: Hm, okay, might be – I interpreted _“and when the button is clicked again it __jumps__ to the second li”_ differently though.

Answer (score 0):

Check out following fiddle example that shows jquery use for the same.

```
    $('ol').find('li').each(function (index) {
        if ($(this).attr('class') != undefined) {
            if (($(this).attr('class')).indexOf('selected') >= 0) {
                if ($length > index + 1) {
                    $(this).removeClass('selected').next().addClass('selected');
                }
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bhimubgm/YkzBt/)